# Impersonal passive construction where the 'es' is implied/omitted

Tags: passive, subject

I am learning about impersonal constructions with 'es'. My textbook says that sometimes the 'es' is implied in such sentences:

> Jetzt wird geschlafen

This is translated as 'it's time to go to sleep now'. However, I don't understand how this meaning is created. It's not intuitive for me.

Is 'Jetzt' the subject of the sentence? Would the non-passive construction be:

> Es ist jetzt Zeit zu schlafen

Why is the passive construction not:

> Es wird jetzt geschlafen

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There simply is no subject in *Jetzt wird geschlafen*.

The sentence mentions nobody specifically, and the impersonal passive does not require a subject.

> Es wird jetzt geschlafen.

is also correct. Here a placeholder-*es* (an *expletive*) is used as a formal subject, filling the first position in the sentence, because *Wird jetzt geschlafen* is only correct as a question, as a statement it would violate the verb-second rule.

> Es ist jetzt Zeit zu schlafen.

is also correct but uses different words to express the meaning.

Also possible but a bit unusual is:

> Geschlafen wird jetzt.