# intransitive verb in passive?

Tags: passive

> Die Polizei sagt, es **wird** von einer organisierten Bande **ausgegangen**.

How come in this sentence the verb "ausgehen" is in the passive voice? I thought the passive voice was only with verbs that comes with an Akkusativ. Please translate this sentence literally to English. The auxiliary verb should have been "sein" not "werden". What do you think guys?

Comment: I don't understand it yet.. Is "Die Polizei sagt, sie gehen von einer org. Bande aus." better?

Comment: It is probably not a duplicate given the specific example, but you can find information on what you're asking about at https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49897/trouble-with-impersonal-passive-voice-usage (among other places - this is a frequently asked question on this platform). For grammatical details, see for instance https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1068 or Helbig/Buscha, Deutsche Grammatik (2001), 145ff (both in German). Exercises for learners can be found in Helbig/Buscha, Übungsgrammatik Deutsch (2000), 64f.

Comment: “Please translate this sentence literally to English.” What’s the point if you are asking about grammar, and English and German grammar differ?

Answer (score 1):

This is indirect speech, so it should be *Konjunktiv I* instead of *Indikativ*:

> Die Polizei sagt, es **werde** von einer organisierten Bande ausgegangen.

Now it is a correct sentence.

---

But now for the passive voice:

You can build the ***unpersönliches Passiv*** with every verb you want. There are two ways to do so:

- Use either an *adverbiale Bestimmung* at position 1:

  > Hier **wird** nicht **geraucht**!
  > Jetzt **wird geschlafen!**
  > Gestern **wurde** viel **getanzt.**
- Or you to fill position 1 with a word that has no semantic meaning, and that is here only for syntactic reasons: the syntactic expletive *es*:

  > Es **wird gemunkelt,** die Impfung wäre schädlich.
  > Es **wird** zu viel **geredet.**
  > Es **wurde** an völlig unpassenden Stellen **gelacht.**

Your sentence belongs to the second group.

Both versions result in a sentence without a subject. Although the expletive *es* looks like a subject, it still is not, because you can move a subject to other places in the sentence, but you can't do this with an expletivum (who's only purpose is to fill position 1 of the sentence):

- Subject on position 1 can move:

  > **Kurt** wurde heute morgen ausgelacht.
  > Heute morgen wurde **Kurt** ausgelacht. <- *correct*
- Expletivum on position 1 can't move:

  > **Es** wurde heute morgen gelacht.
  > Heute morgen wurde **es** gelacht. <- *wrong*
  > Heute morgen wurde gelacht. <- *correct*

Comment: Actually there are a few verbs from which no passive at all can be formed (*Nicht passivfähige Verben*), for example *bekommen*.